# Get Computer Model witn WMIC

Tags: vb6, wmic

I'm, unable to retrieve the PC model in VB6, the property I request from the query returns empty. I try to emulate the result of this CMD command.

```
wmic computersystem get model
```

This is the code I try to use. (I added Microsoft WMI scripting lib 1.2 as a reference in the project).

```
Function wmiInfo() As String
   Dim List
   Dim Msg
   Dim Object

   On Local Error Resume Next

   Set List = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf("Win32_BaseBoard")
   For Each Object In List
      Msg = Msg & "Motherboard Serial Number: " & Object.Model & vbCrLf
   Next

   MsgBox Msg
end function
```

I expect the function to retrieve just a string with the model of the PC something like "Optiplex 790" (it is what the cmd command returns).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

(OS Windows 7)

Comment: Is the list getting populated with anything at all?  Or how else is it going wrong?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Thanks for taking the time to get into the issue. I re-read my post and I think I mislead you with the info. The query is successful. If I use the property "GetObjectText_" all the information of the Win32_BaseBoard is retrieved. However, that is the key to what I'm looking for, Win32_BaseBoard is not what I need to query, Win32_ComputerSystem is what I needed. So silly, the "cmd command" I posted had the actual answer. Anyway, without your comment, I probably wouldn't be able to get to the answer.

Comment: Glad it helped even if only tangentially :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was requesting the wrong class.
Win32_computerSystem has the property I'm looking for.

```
Function wmiProcessorInfo() As String
    Dim msg As String
    Dim cpuSet As SWbemObjectSet
    Dim cpu As SWbemObject
    Dim itmx As ListItem

    On Local Error Resume Next

    Set cpuSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each cpu In cpuSet
       msg = cpu.Model
    Next

    MsgBox msg
End Function
```